# keyword "Content" coming instead of actual keyword in Google Adwords Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-ads-api

I am encountering issue in fetching the keywords report with google adwords api.
Everything else is coming proper but for some keywords its giving "Content" as keword text.
Please could any one suggest me what should I do to get actual keyword.

I am using gem 'google-adwords-api'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is a special fake keyword returned by AdWords for the "contextual display" stats for each ad group. (the actual per-keyword stats on the display network are given in the separate `DISPLAY_KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`)

From the official developer guides: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting-concepts#keywordid3000000

> In single attribution reports, all keywords that triggered impressions
> on the display network will be represented by a special keyword (text:
> Content) with ID 3000000.
>
> Example
>
> Keyword ID,Impressions
>
> 23458623485,2
>
> 23655322314,2
>
> 23953456345,2
>
> 3000000,4
>
> If you target keywords and placements for Display Only and
> run an Ad Performance report, you'll get a row for each ad and
> triggering criteria combination for placements, and a single row with
> ad and ID 3000000 which accounts for all the display keywords that
> triggered that ad (where single attribution chose the keyword rather
> than a placement).

Comment: Actually I am storing the data on local so, do i need to